# Achieving the effect of a sealed class in Swift

Tags: swift, final, sealed, associated-types

I'm trying to achieve the effect of Kotlin sealed class in Swift, so that I can implement a class-based alternative to enums with associated types.

The following results in a compiler error:

```
final class Foo {
    class Bar: Foo {}  // Error: inheritance from a final class "Foo"
}
```

Is there a way to effectively "seal" a Swift class from further subclassing but still allow subclassing in the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would give a look at this
[Using Kotlin’s sealed class to approximate Swift’s enum with associated data](https://medium.com/@da_pacheco/using-kotlins-sealed-class-to-approximate-swift-s-enum-with-associated-data-7e0abac88bbf) and (mostly) this
[Swift Enumerations Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145)

**Kotlin**:

```
sealed class Barcode {
   class upc(val numberSystem: Int, val manufacturer: Int, val product: Int, val check: Int) : Barcode()
   class qrCode(val productCode: String) : Barcode()
}
```

and then:

```
fun barcodeAsString(barcode: Barcode): String =
   when (barcode) {
      is Barcode.upc -> “${barcode.numberSystem} ${barcode.manufacturer} 
   ${barcode.product} ${barcode.check}”
      is Barcode.qrCode -> “${barcode.productCode}”
}
```

While in **Swift**:

```
enum Barcode {
   case upc(Int, Int, Int, Int)
   case qrCode(String)
}
```

And then do things like:

```
var productBarcode = Barcode.upc(8, 85909, 51226, 3)
productBarcode = .qrCode("SDFGHJKLYFF")
```

or:

```
switch productBarcode {
case .upcA(let a, let b, let c, let d):
    print("UPC: \(a),\(b),\(c),\(d)")
case .qrCode(let code):
    print("QR Code: \(code)")
}
```

Comment: This is so elegant! clean! yes! Well after 9 years of android development and 3 with Kotlin, I really loved the way Kotlin treats its users with clean and tidy code, so this approach makes swift code even cleaner! love it!

Answer (score 4):

You could put it and its subclass in a framework and mark it `public`. A `public` class cannot be subclassed by its importer (as opposed to an `open` class which can).